# Accessing to the last element in Z3 list

Tags: z3

How can I access the last element in Z3 list?

```
(declare-const lst (List Int))
(assert (not (= lst nil)))
(assert (= (head lst) 1))
(assert (= (last_element lst) 2))
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Z3 has no built-in function to access the last element of a list. Since SMT-Lib2 does not support recursive functions (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478559/491216)), you have to declare and axiomatise an uninterpreted `last_element` function yourself.

Declaration:

```
(declare-fun last_element ((List Int) (Int)) Bool)
```

Axiom "*nil* has no last element":

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (!
  (not (last_element nil x))
  :pattern ((last_element nil x))
)))
```

Axiom "If *xs* is the list *x:nil* then *x* is the last element of *xs*":

```
(assert (forall ((xs (List Int)) (x Int)) (!
  (implies
    (= xs (insert x nil))
    (last_element xs x))
  :pattern ((last_element xs x))
)))
```

Axiom "If *x* is the last element of the tail of *xs*, then it is also the last element of *xs* itself":

```
(assert (forall ((xs (List Int)) (x Int)) (!
  (implies
    (last_element (tail xs) x)
    (last_element xs x))
  :pattern ((last_element xs x))
)))
```

See this [rise4fun-link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/GZYD) for an example.

**Please note**: The linked example switches of model based quantifier instantiation (MBQI, see the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide)) and thus relies on E-matching. This is also the reason why explicit patterns are provided, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120972/different-ways-of-axiomatising-a-contains-function-for-z3-lists). If you want to give MBQI a try you might have to change the axiomatisation, but I hardly know anything about MBQI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if we change `(assert (not (last_element xs 3)))` to `(assert (last_element xs 3))` we shall obtain UNSAT too. Why?

Comment: @user2475120 Sorry, my bad. The third axiom used `iff` instead of `implies`, which let to a contradiction with the first axiom in case `xs = x:nil`.