# Show what patterns Z3 infers for quantifiers

Tags: triggers, z3, quantifiers

I would like to see what patterns Z3 is using for some quantifiers in my formulas.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120972/different-ways-of-axiomatising-a-contains-function-for-z3-lists#comment14635783_11127147) suggests that it may be possible, but I couldn't find any more details.

How do I get Z3 to print this information?

Comment: Currently you can only print this information via debug traces in debug mode, there is no convenient way to display that information in a readable way. It's still on the todo-list and I've started adding some things toward this in a separate branch, but it will still take time to make that convenient to use.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Can you tell me how to do it in debug mode (even if it's unreadable)?

Comment: I found a way to do it using a debug build of Z3. I remain hopeful that this will be possible in normal builds someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866447/show-what-patterns-z3-infers-for-quantifiers#comment78692532_45866447) from Christoph, I found that building Z3 in debug mode (pass `-d` to `mk_make.py` during the build process) and then passing `-v:10` on the command line to the resulting Z3 prints inferred patterns.

Comment: The printout of the inferred patterns was a recent addition and only for debugging. The way to enable that and the format of the output a very likely to change very soon, so don't depend on it. (Also, it prints only the inferred patterns, and possibly not all of them.)

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I plan to use this only for debugging, so these limitations aren't a huge deal.